# How can I parse a string with the format "1/16/2019 1:24:51" into a POSIXct or other date variable?

Tags: r, datetime

I'm reading in google sheets csv's and the date is a column of strings that looks like this

"1/16/2019 1:24:51"

I have tried:
`as.POSIXct("1/16/2019 1:24:51", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

However, as the month and hour are not zero-padded it doesn't work (at least I think that's the reason).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero-padding is not the reason.  The `day` (`%d`) and `month` (`%m`) should be reversed as month cannot have values greater than 12

```
as.POSIXct("1/16/2019 1:24:51", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2019-01-16 01:24:51 EST"
```

Comment: Oh boy.. silly me.. :-) thx!